# Get an error when trying to import the exported variable in another file nodejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a file called TemplateGenerator and I have:

```
export const test= {
    "type": "bundle"
}
export const bundle= {
    "type": "bundle",
    "id": "bundle--bb7142cc-83d5-4feb-98c7-53997d25c368",
    "objects": [generateObservedDataObj(),generateObservedDataObj(),generateObservedDataObj()]
}
```

So when I try to import it in another js file called Results like this:

```
import {bundle} from '../utils/TemplateGenerator';
```

I get

```
 SyntaxError: The requested module 'file:///app/src/results/Results.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routers/Routes.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/server.js:1)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
export default const ...
```

since it is the only function/variable exported.

Comment: I have more than one export

Answer (score 0):

First, declare the variable, then export it

```js
const bundle= {
    "type": "bundle",
    "id": "bundle--bb7142cc-83d5-4feb-98c7-53997d25c368",
    "objects": [generateObservedDataObj(),generateObservedDataObj(),generateObservedDataObj()]
}

export default bundle;
```

Comment: did not work and also what if I have more than one export.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
 SyntaxError: The requested module 'file:///app/src/results/Results.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Probably indicates that you import `Result.js` wrong. Are you sure that `import {bundle} from '../utils/TemplateGenerator'` actually is the root of your problem? Did you maybe import `Result` like this: `import { default } from './wherever/Result.js'`?